# How to extract features from a 3D Dicom Image

Tags: image-processing, dicom, feature-extraction, borland-c++

I am working on a project that needs to extract features from the medical images (.DICOM). I am working on Borland C++. I have never worked on such a project. Can you provide me some useful resources or algorithms to extract 3D images' features?

Answer (score 0):

With such a vague question (what kind of features?) it's only possible to provide a vague answer. A couple algorithms which come to mind are rough set based feature selection, and genetic algorithm based feature selection. For genetic algorithms, a pretty good walkthrough with examples may be found here:

https://topepo.github.io/caret/feature-selection-using-genetic-algorithms.html

And for rough set based selection, a very thorough description may be found here:

https://wiki.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2013-14/F/4403/_media/roughsetmethods.pdf

More details on your features would lead to more specifics on suggested algorithms.